# Django : Edit the many to many field Inline using Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to edit the cuisines associated with a dish on the dish panel in django admin. I am trying to use **InlineModelAdmin**. The problem is that I can edit the DishCuisinesMap objects but not the cuisines object.
Here is the **screenshot**:

[image: screenshot]

This is my models.py:

```
class Cuisines(models.Model):
    cuisine_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cuisine_mtom = models.ManyToManyField('DishInfo', through='DishCuisinesMap')
    name = models.TextField()
    cuisine_sf_name = models.TextField() 
    type = models.IntegerField()
    insert_time = models.DateTimeField()
    update_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cuisines'

class DishCuisinesMap(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey('DishInfo', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                             related_name='dcm_dish')
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey(Cuisines, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                related_name='dcm_cuisine')
    insert_time = models.DateTimeField()
    update_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dish_cuisines_map'
        unique_together = (('dish', 'cuisine'),)


class DishInfo(models.Model):
    dish_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Brands, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='bid',
                            related_name='dinfo_brand')
    name = models.TextField()
    is_live = models.IntegerField()
    veg_nonveg_ind = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sf_name = models.TextField()
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    expert_tag = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    special_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    reco_percent = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    one_liner = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    nutrition = JSONField() 
    insert_time = models.DateTimeField()
    update_time = models.DateTimeField()
    images = ArrayField(models.TextField()) 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dish_info'
        unique_together = (('bid', 'name'), ('bid', 'sf_name'),)

    def __unicode__(self):
        brand_name = self.bid.name
        return self.name
```

and this is my admin.py:

```
class CityDishFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = ('city name')
    parameter_name = 'city_id'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        list_of_cities = list()
        queryset = Cities.objects.all()
        for city in queryset:
            list_of_cities.append(
                    (str(city.city_id), city.name)
                )
        return list_of_cities

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        query_params = request.GET  
        if self.value():
            city_query = DelLocations.objects.filter(city__city_id=self.value())\
                                                                        .values('del_id')
            loc_query = DelLocationsMapping.objects.filter(del_loc__in=
                                                        city_query).values('plot')
            dopm_query = DishOutletPlatMapping.objects.filter(plot__in
                                                        =loc_query).values('dish')
            final_query = DishInfo.objects.filter(dish_id__in=dopm_query)
            if 'veg_nonveg_ind' in query_params:
                final_query = final_query.filter(veg_nonveg_ind=query_params.get('veg_nonveg_ind'))

            if 'is_live' in query_params:
                final_query = final_query.filter(is_live=query_params.get('is_live'))
            return final_query
        return queryset


class BrandDishFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = ('brand name')
    parameter_name = 'brand_id'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        query_params = request.GET
        list_of_brands = list()
        if 'city_id' in query_params:
            city_query = DelLocations.objects.filter(city__city_id=query_params.get('city_id'))\
                                                                        .values('del_id')
            loc_query = DelLocationsMapping.objects.filter(del_loc__in=
                                                        city_query).values('plot')
            dopm_query = DishOutletPlatMapping.objects.filter(plot__in
                                                        =loc_query).values('dish')
            dish_query = DishInfo.objects.filter(dish_id__in=dopm_query).\
                                                            values('bid').distinct()
            brand_query = Brands.objects.filter(bid__in=dish_query).order_by('name')
            for brand in brand_query:
                list_of_brands.append(
                        (str(brand.bid), brand.name)
                    )
            return list_of_brands
        else:
            brand_query = Brands.objects.all().order_by('name')
            for brand in brand_query:
                list_of_brands.append(
                        (str(brand.bid), brand.name)
                    )
            return list_of_brands

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if 'brand_id' in request.GET:
            queryset = queryset.filter(bid=self.value())
            return queryset
        return queryset

class DishCuisinesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DishCuisinesMap
    extra = 1

class CuisinesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DishCuisinesInline,]
    fields = ("name", "cuisine_sf_name", "type")

class DishInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = ('bid',)
    list_display = ('name', 'brand_name')
    fieldsets = (
                    (None, {'fields': ('name', 'sf_name', 'is_live', 'veg_nonveg_ind',
                                        'one_liner',
                                      )
                            }
                    ),
                    ('Advanced options', {'classes': ('collapse',),
                                           'fields': ('descr', 'images')
                                         }
                    )
                )
    search_fields = ['name', 'bid__name']
    list_filter = ('veg_nonveg_ind', 'is_live', CityDishFilter, BrandDishFilter) #, 'bid__name'
    inlines = [DishTimingsInline, DishCuisinesInline]

    # changing the size of the text fields:
    formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(
                       attrs = {'rows': 4,
                              'cols': 50})
                        },
                    }


    def brand_name(self, obj):
        return obj.bid.name


admin.site.register(DishInfo, DishInfoAdmin)
admin.site.register(Cuisines, CuisinesAdmin)
```

The django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) say that membership objects can be edited from Person or the Group detail pages, but what is way to edit the group from the person details page?
In my case I need a way to edit the cuisines from the dish page , I am pretty new to django. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As of now djnago doesn't support nested inlines [Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025). You might have to use libraries like [djnago-nested-inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) or [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin)

Comment: I tried this  [link](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) , but it did'nt fit to my use case. I am actually having a many to many relationship via through model (DishCuisinesMap).